# n choose r deck of cards question

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find out the probability of getting a pair out of a standard deck of cards where the dealt hand is 5 cards. My teacher says it is: $$\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{2} \binom{50}{3}$$

However, for my answer I got: $$\binom{4}{1} \binom{13}{1} \binom{3}{1} \binom{50}{3}$$ where you first choose a suit, then one of the cards, and then the matching pair from one of the other 3 suits, and then the other 3 cards. Why is my way incorrect?

Comment: Both answers are wrong unless you wish to permit three or more cards of the same rank to be selected.  Normally, selecting a pair means that you select two cards of one rank and one card each from three other ranks.  The factor of $\binom{50}{3}$ in both your answers allows you to take any three cards from the deck in addition to the pair, which means you could obtain three of a kind, two pairs, a full house, or four of a kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is taking *order* into consideration (which suit *first*, which suit *second*), whereas your teacher's answer does not (simply pick two of the four suits).

To compensate, you would have to divide your answer by $2!$, to disregard the order of the suits. Then the two answers match.

Comment: So my way is basically like taking an r-permutation P(4, 2)?

Comment: Yes: your teacher did $C(4,2)$, whereas you did $P(4,2)$. It's a very subtle difference.

Answer (score 2):

They are both incorrect because, for example, the event of getting a triple with two unmatched other cards is counted three times by your teacher and six times by you. It should either be counted once or not at all (if you want to regard a triple as different from a pair).